# Watcher resets when data is filled in other inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form where the user enters data and sends it to the server, there are 2 selects, the options of which are filled with data from the server, there are 2 selects: 1 for countries, the other for cities, when a country is selected, the select is updated with the cities of the corresponding country. To do this, I created a watcher that is responsible for updating the list of cities:

```
'form.countryID': function(){
        this.cities = this.COUNTRIES.filter(item => {
            return item.id == this.form.countryID;
        })[0].cities;
    }
```

COUNTRIES is a getter from vuex, I make a get request in the store.
This is my select with cities:

```
                <select 
                    type="text" 
                    class="questionnaire__questions-input questionnaire__input"
                    v-model="form.cityID"
                    :class="$v.form.cityID.$error ? 'questionnaire-input-invalid' : ''">
                    <option value="">Выберите город</option>
                    
                    <option v-for="city in cities" :key="city.id" :value="form.cityID">{{city.name}}</option>
                    
                </select>
```

The problem is that I have other inputs in the form, and when I enter a value there, my select with cities is reset, I don’t understand what could be the problem? Other inputs are not tied to the select, or to the value of the cities.

Comment: Can you check if by mistake you are using the same v-model binding `form.cityID` on other inputs?

Comment: @NehaSoni i check it, all good

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet here instead of only two code snippets, so debugging would be easy?